# Objective-Cの自作Frameworkでリリースビルドを行なった際にBitcodeに関するエラーが発生します。

Tags: objective-c, build, framework

お世話になります。

自分で使用する様に自作フレームワーク（Cocoa Touch Framewok）を開発しました。
このフレームワークをアプリに組み込み、Archiveを開こうとしたところ、ビルド時に以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because 'フレームワークのパス' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file 'フレームワークのパス' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

色々調べた結果、
「Build Setting」の「Apple Clang - Custom Compiler Flags」の「Other C Flags」に「-fembed-bitcode」を設定する必要があるとの事だったので設定しましたが、同様の結果です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

お手数をお掛け致しますが、対応方法に関してご教示頂けますでしょうか。

Comment: Bitcode埋め込みが必須でなければ、生成アプリケーション側でのBitcode出力を無効化するのが手っ取り早い気はします。